# Multiple belongs_to in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm rather confused by the `belongs_to` associations in Rails when it comes to associating a comment with both the User and Page.  What I am saying is there a way to associate a comment with both the user and page?  Take the following (simple example that doesn't work for me but demonstrates):

```
# The basic idea is that I would like to have User show comments from the user
# on all pages, and Page show all the comments for the page.
# User.find_by_email('email@domain.com').comments # Show comments on pages.
# Page.find_by_slug('my-slug').comments # Show comments on the page.

class Comments
  include Mongoid::Document and include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include MyApp::Mongoid::Patches::DefaultType

  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :user

  field :content, type: String
end

class Page
  include Mongoid::Document and include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include MyApp::Mongoid::Patches::DefaultType

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  field :type, type: String, default: :post
  field :slug, type: String
  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String
  field :tags, type: Array, default: :user

  private
  # .....
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document and include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include MyApp::Mongoid::Patches::DefaultType

  embeds_one :provider
  has_many :pages
  has_many :comments # But only from Pages not on the user.

  field :email, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :role, type: Symbol, default: :user
end
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Having multiple belongs_to is a 100% correct, there's nothing special about it.

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto For me it's not creating the double association at all.

Comment: Don't know how mongodb works, but you're supposed to have foreign keys in the table that has the belongs_to. So here in `comments` table you need `user_id` and `page_id`

Comment: Do you want `User -> Page -> Comment` association or `User -> Comment <- Page`? `->` denotes `has_many`. In the former case user `has_many :comments, :through => :page`. In your code you have a loop (`User -> Page -> Comments` and `User -> Comments` at the same time, both direct).

Comment: It's still not clear to me what does not work. Could you try to describe in more detail (examples?) what does not work as expected.

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto MOngoid creates the relations automatically so if I do Page.comment.build it will add the association on the document dynamically with the BSON Object.

Comment: @VictorMoroz :through is exactly what I wanted but I guess Mongoid doesn't work with that so I guess with Mongoid I'll never be able to do User.comments == User.page.comments == Page.comments without adding those methods to forward myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for here is a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Check out that link for the official Rails guide to polymorphic associations, but in a nutshell, you would do something like this:

```
class Comments
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class User
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Page
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

Now add two fields commentable_type(string) and commentable_id(integer) in your comments table.

Now your users and pages can both have comments.

if comment is a Comment object you can use comment.commentable to get User/Page of that comment

Comment: I want the comments associated with the user and page (I guess a double association) so that I can pull the users comments on pages and posts via their User record without having to tap into Comments or Page directly but also when they post a comment just use Page.comments.create!

Comment: if you have a User object -> user then  you can use user.comments to get all comments associated with that user but I am not sure what you really want